# Android ListView in DialogFragment bugs when using setStyle

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I have a problem using DialogFragment with a ListView in it. The problem arises when I use setStyle in onCreate.

Here is the code (to be clearer about the issue, I have colored the list textviews in magenta) :

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MenuDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public static MenuDialog create() {
        MenuDialog frag = new MenuDialog();
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ListView v = new ListView(getActivity());
        v.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                TextView view = null;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    view = new TextView(getActivity());
                    view.setTextAppearance(getActivity(), android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
                    view.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                }
                else
                    view = (TextView) convertView;

                switch (position) {
                case 0: view.setText("Random"); break;
                case 1: view.setText("Community favourites"); break;
                case 2: view.setText("Change image"); break;
                case 3: view.setText("Share"); break;
                case 4: view.setText("Informations"); break;
                }

                return view;
            }

            @Override public long getItemId(int arg0) { return 0; }
            @Override public Object getItem(int arg0) { return null; }
            @Override public int getCount() { return 5; }
        });
        return v;
    }
}
```

And here is the image of the dialog it provides :

[image: No title: Not working]

Now, if I simply comment the setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0); line in the onCreate method, everything works as expected :

[image: With title : works]

What am I doing wrong ?
I cannot use a simple AlertDialog because I need to customize way more those list items.

**EDIT:** [You can download here a demo Android Eclipse project that demonstrates the problem](http://www.mediafire.com/?jkjrza639a2dzz5)

Comment: Hi, Salomon BRYS problem has been solved.Check edit answer

Comment: after testing it,please inform its fine or not?

Answer (score 2):

1. list.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ListView
       android:id="@+id/list"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        />

    </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. menu_rowview.xml

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:id="@+id/linear"
            >

          <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
             android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
             android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
             android:text="@android:string/unknownName"
             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            </LinearLayout>
   ```
3. Change onCreateView() (in your project)

   ```
     public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container);
   ListView v=(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
   v.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {

       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           View rowView = null;
           if (convertView == null) {
               rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_rowview, parent, false);

           }
           else
               rowView = convertView;
           LinearLayout lay=(LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.linear);
           lay.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
           TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
           switch (position) {
           case 0: textView.setText("Random"); break;
           case 1: textView.setText("Community favourites"); break;
           case 2: textView.setText("Change image"); break;
           case 3: textView.setText("Share"); break;
           case 4: textView.setText("Informations"); break;
           }

           return rowView;
       }

       @Override public long getItemId(int arg0) { 
           return arg0; }
       @Override public Object getItem(int arg0) { return arg0; }
       @Override public int getCount() { return 5; }
   });
   return view;
   }
   ```

Comment: problem is you set backgrounnd color of textview not row

Comment: This does not solve the problem. I have created an archive with a demo project, [you can download it here](http://www.mediafire.com/?jkjrza639a2dzz5).

Comment: I've run your demo project on galaxy tab (android 3.2) and galaxy s (android 4.0.4). Both styles works fine. (Rows are filled with pink color in both cases).

Comment: I've only tested on Jelly Bean... I guess it's a platform bug then

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:minWidth="360dp"` on your `TextView`

Answer (score 1):

use this code in onCreate method

`getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Comment: geDialog() returns null inside onCreate() and you get a java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: try  `getActivity().getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Answer (score 0):

This issue driving me crazy all day today, it is definitely a bug in a system. What I ended up doing to work it around is I left STYLE_NO_TITLE since I really don't want to deal with title, my other styles for dialog goes in theme:

```
fragment.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.Dialog);
```

This of course will bring the issue on some phones, which is not just matter of background, but also a touchable area. Now the nasty hacky fix is in my item xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:height="48dp"
    android:width="600dp"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    />
```

Hardcoding width to large value makes a trick, but I'm not quite sure how does it affect performance on lo-res devices though. Tested on Kindle Fire, Nexus 7 and emulators from 2.2
Hope this will help someone